# Dev Tools - Elasticsearch Incorrect HTTP method for Uri

Tags: http, elasticsearch, post, get

I have ElasticSearch Kibana v7.12 and when I open up the localhost:5601 in the Management tab -> Dev Tools. I am trying to run a post method but whenever I try to execute the method it tells me Incorrect HTTP method, I do not understand why if I am including `/_doc` in the url. The GET method works just fine. I am very new to this, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated it!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From 7.x whenever you index a document you need to include `_doc` in the URL. This is just for representing an endpoint name.**

From the official [elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#_schedule_for_removal_of_mapping_types)

> in 7.0, _doc is a permanent part of the path and represents the
> endpoint name rather than the document type.
>
> From 8.0 Specifying types in requests is no longer supported.